# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x and y

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I don't see why this does not work:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(-4,4,0.01)
g <- qplot(x, dnorm(x), geom = 'line')
g <- g + labs(x = 'x', y = 'f(x)', title = 'Distribución normal estándar')
g
title <- expression(paste('N(0,1) ', italic(versus), ' N(1,1)'))
g <- g + stat_function(fun = dnorm(x), args = list(mean = 1), color = 'red')
g <- g + labs(title = title)
g
```

I get

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x and y

But it worked previously!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when you add a (any!) data frame as `data` argument. Maybe you have used a data frame in your previous code. I usually don't work with `qplot`, but if this is similar to ggplot, it usually needs some specifications to which data you refer to. In this case, you can simply create a "dummy" argument.

Note I have also changed the `fun` argument to simply `dnorm`. No brackets or argument needed.

```r
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(-4,4,0.01)
qplot(x, dnorm(x), geom = 'line') + 
  stat_function(data = data.frame(), fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 1), color = 'red')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>